# Warning: mysqli_free_result() expects exactly 1 parameter, 2 given

Tags: php, mysqli, pagination

I have some code for paginating data. My data is showing, but the pagination is not working. I get the following error:

> Warning: mysqli_free_result() expects exactly 1 parameter, 2 given

Previously, my pagination worked using **mysql**, before I changed `mysql_result()` to `mysqli_free_result()`.

This is my code:

```
<table class="table table-striped table-hover fill-head">
 <thead>
  <tr>
   <th>Code Poli</th>
   <th>Name Poli</th>
   <th>Floor</th>
   <th style="width: 150px">Action</th>
  </tr>
 </thead>
 <tbody>

<?php 

  $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","klinik");
  $per_page = 2;
  $query = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM poliknik";
  $page_query = mysqli_query($con,$query);
  $pages = ceil(mysqli_free_result($page_query, 0) / $per_page);
  $page = (isset($_GET['hal'])) ? (int)$_GET['hal'] : 1;
  $start = ($page - 1) * $per_page;         
  $data_kg=mysqli_query($con,"select * from poliknik order by id_poli DESC LIMIT $start,$per_page");
  while ($kg=mysqli_fetch_object($data_kg)){

?>

  <tr>
   <td><?php echo $kg->kode?></td>
   <td><?php echo $kg->name_poli?></td>
   <td><?php echo $kg->lt?></td>
   <td>
   <a class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" href="home.php?p=edit_poliknik&id_poli=<?php echo $kg->id_poli ?>"><i class="fa fa-edit"></i> Edit</a>
   <a class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" href="home.php?p=hapus_poliknik&id_poli=<?php echo $kg->id_poli ?>"><i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i> Delete</a>

   </td>
  </tr>

<?php } ?>

 </tbody>
</table>
<center>
 <div>
  <ul class="pagination pagination-lg pagination-colory">

<?php

  if($pages >= 1 && $page <= $pages){
    for($x=1; $x<=$pages; $x++){    
      echo ($x == $page) ? '<li class="active"><a href="home.php?p=poliknik&hal='.$x.'">'.$x.'</a></li>' : '<li><a href="home.php?p=poliknik&hal='.$x.'">'.$x.'</a></li>';
    }
  } 

?>

  </ul>
 </div>
</center>
```

You can check my pagination code using **mysql** > http://pastebin.com/CkyazRZM

Comment: The error/warning is obvious, isn't it?

Comment: @Fred-ii- Obviously the error message needs to fix the code too in order to help him.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit this line

```
$pages = ceil(mysqli_free_result($page_query, 0) / $per_page);
```

to

```
$pages = ceil(mysqli_fetch_array($page_query)[0] / $per_page);
mysqli_free_result($page_query);
```

Comment: Cool, error not show again
but my pagging, stil not show :'(

Comment: mysqli_free_result() returns boolean. So, are you dividing a boolean value? Edited..try the edited solution

Comment: so you can give me a solution ?

Comment: refresh your page and try the solution given by me.

Comment: Notice: Object of class mysqli_result could not be converted to int in poliknik.php on line 49

$pages = ceil($page_query / $per_page);   // THIS LINE 49
mysqli_free_result($page_query);

Comment: Refresh your page and Try it now! It will be alright!

Comment: Wow, that's great

thank's sailesh :)

Answer (score 0):

The MySQLi extension doesn't have a `mysqli_result` function (it has a [`mysqli_result`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.mysqli-result.php) *class*), and the [`mysqli_free_result`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.free.php) function does something else entirely.

You have to fetch the row and access the data using [`mysqli_fetch_row()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-row.php) or similar:

```
$query = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM poliknik";
$page_query = mysqli_query($con,$query);
$r = mysqli_fetch_row ($page_query);
$count = $r[0];
$pages = ceil($count / $per_page);
```

Don't forget to check the return values of `mysqli_query()` and `mysqli_fetch_row()`, and handle errors appropriately.